# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - OneToMany

Tags: mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, relational-database

I want to create an online shop. I have defined an user table and an order table with one to many relationship between them. I want to insert something in this tables and I received this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`restaurant_java`.`order_food`, CONSTRAINT `fk_order_food_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Here is how can I created the tables and how I defined the contrains.

User table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id              INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    firstname       VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    lastname        VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    cnp             VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
    email           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    password        VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    phone           VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    iban            VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    address         VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT pk_users_id PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Order food:

```
CREATE TABLE order_food (
    id          INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    user_id     INT(10) UNSIGNED,
    created     datetime DEFAULT NOW(),
    closed      datetime,
    total       float,
    KEY(id)
);
ALTER TABLE order_food ADD CONSTRAINT pk_order_food_id PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE order_food ADD CONSTRAINT fk_order_food_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I would also like to add that I tried to insert with hibernate to the mySql database. How can I resolve this issue?

**Edit:**
Here is how I tried to insert a new user:

```
session.beginTransaction();

Collection<OrderFoodEntity> orderFoodEntities = new HashSet<>();
OrderFoodEntity orderFoodEntity = new OrderFoodEntity();

orderFoodEntity.setTotal((float) 0);
orderFoodEntities.add(orderFoodEntity);
user.setOrderFoodsById(orderFoodEntities);
user.addOrder();

session.persist(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

And the entities is here:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "", catalog = "restaurant_java")
public class UsersEntity {
    private int id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String cnp;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String phone;
    private String iban;
    private String address;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usersByUserId", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Collection<OrderFoodEntity> orderFoodsById;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 200)
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 200)
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "cnp", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 13)
    public String getCnp() {
        return cnp;
    }

    public void setCnp(String cnp) {
        this.cnp = cnp;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 50)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 100)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 10)
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "iban", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 20)
    public String getIban() {
        return iban;
    }

    public void setIban(String iban) {
        this.iban = iban;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 200)
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void addOrder() {
        for (OrderFoodEntity orderFoodEntity : orderFoodsById) {
            orderFoodEntity.setUsersByUserId(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        UsersEntity that = (UsersEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (firstname != null ? !firstname.equals(that.firstname) : that.firstname != null) return false;
        if (lastname != null ? !lastname.equals(that.lastname) : that.lastname != null) return false;
        if (cnp != null ? !cnp.equals(that.cnp) : that.cnp != null) return false;
        if (email != null ? !email.equals(that.email) : that.email != null) return false;
        if (password != null ? !password.equals(that.password) : that.password != null) return false;
        if (phone != null ? !phone.equals(that.phone) : that.phone != null) return false;
        if (iban != null ? !iban.equals(that.iban) : that.iban != null) return false;
        if (address != null ? !address.equals(that.address) : that.address != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (firstname != null ? firstname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastname != null ? lastname.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (cnp != null ? cnp.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (phone != null ? phone.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (iban != null ? iban.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (address != null ? address.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }


    public Collection<OrderFoodEntity> getOrderFoodsById() {
        return orderFoodsById;
    }

    public void setOrderFoodsById(Collection<OrderFoodEntity> orderFoodsById) {
        this.orderFoodsById = orderFoodsById;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UsersEntity{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
                ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
                ", cnp='" + cnp + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
                ", iban='" + iban + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", order= " + orderFoodsById +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_food", schema = "", catalog = "restaurant_java")
public class OrderFoodEntity {
    private int id;
    private int userId;
    private Timestamp created;
    private Timestamp closed;
    private Float total;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private UsersEntity usersByUserId;
    private Collection<OrderLineEntity> orderLinesById;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "created", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "closed", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public Timestamp getClosed() {
        return closed;
    }

    public void setClosed(Timestamp closed) {
        this.closed = closed;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "total", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, precision = 0)
    public Float getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Float total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        OrderFoodEntity that = (OrderFoodEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (userId != that.userId) return false;
        if (created != null ? !created.equals(that.created) : that.created != null) return false;
        if (closed != null ? !closed.equals(that.closed) : that.closed != null) return false;
        if (total != null ? !total.equals(that.total) : that.total != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + userId;
        result = 31 * result + (created != null ? created.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (closed != null ? closed.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (total != null ? total.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }


    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    public UsersEntity getUsersByUserId() {
        return usersByUserId;
    }

    public void setUsersByUserId(UsersEntity usersByUserId) {
        this.usersByUserId = usersByUserId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderFoodByOrderId")
    public Collection<OrderLineEntity> getOrderLinesById() {
        return orderLinesById;
    }

    public void setOrderLinesById(Collection<OrderLineEntity> orderLinesById) {
        this.orderLinesById = orderLinesById;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OrderFoodEntity{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", userId=" + userId +
                ", created=" + created +
                ", closed=" + closed +
                ", total=" + total +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your insert query or at least the code you use to insert data?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the column `user_id` in table `order_line`. What you have is `order_id` which does not make sense since you have an `id` in this TABLE already.

Make sure this is correct and also make sure you insert in your `order_id` (or `user_id` which I think that should be your case) an existing `id` from your `users` TABLE.